# Getting CORS error with angular and aspnet core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core webapi and im trying to post to it with an Angular6 app.
On the GET request it works fine, but when I try to make a post I always get this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access

What I tried. Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowCors",
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .WithMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("AllowCors");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

And In my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowCors")]
public class SearchController : Controller {
    //code

   //Here I get the error
   [HttpPost("{term}")]
   public async Task SaveSearch([FromBody]dynamic request, string term)
   {
        _searchRepository.SaveSearch(term, request);
   }
}
```

On Angular app:

```
saveSearch(term: string, res:any) {
  this.http.post(`${this.serviceEndpoint}${term}`, {
    term: term, origin: res.countryCode, request: res
  }).subscribe();
});
```

EDIT:

I put the OPTIONS method too, but still getting the error.

Comment: I see `services.AddCors(...)` is there one where you have `app.UseCors(...);` under `Configure()`?

Comment: `.WithMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")`

Comment: @penleychan yes! i have it, edited the OP

Comment: @RitwickDey I put the method OPTIONS, and still getting the error.

Comment: @RitwickDey sorry, its working now.

Comment: @gog You will be able to solve your issue by heading to this like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS means that you have to configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with a value of `*` (for all) on your application server.

Since Angular is making pre-flight requests, I highly recommend to add `OPTIONS` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` configuration.

This is highly depended on the servers you're using, but you didn't state how you served your application. ;)